# Managing more than two parameters in a prepared update statement in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

**This first example works fine:**

```
$.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url:    "test.php",
     data: { title: title, authors: authors},
     }).done(function( data ) {
    alert(data);
});
```

**And in test.php:**

```
$sql='UPDATE books SET title = ?, authors = ? WHERE book_id = 750';
$title =  $_POST['title'];
$authors =  $_POST['authors'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if($stmt === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
/* Bind parameters. TYpes: s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob */
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$title,$authors);
```

**However, it doesn't work when I add an extra parameter in both pieces of code eg:**

```
$.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url:    "test.php",
     data: { title: title, authors: authors, subtitle:subtitle},
     }).done(function( data ) {
    alert(data);
});
```

**In test.php:**

```
$sql='UPDATE books SET title = ?, authors = ?, subtitle = ? WHERE book_id = 750';
$title =  $_POST['title'];
$authors =  $_POST['authors'];
$subtitle =  $_POST['subtitle'];


$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if($stmt === false) {
    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
$stmt->bind_param('sss',$title,$authors,$subtitle);
```

It’s virtually the same code except for the sql statement and the bind parameters so I imagine the problem is there.  I can’t find any examples in books or on the internet of more than 2 parameters in the sql statement and I have tried without commas, all with commas, with double speechmarks, with AND –and none of them are working.  This is not a real application, by the way - It’s a learning project.

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Are you using PDO or mysqli?

Comment: Pointy - it doesn't update the database.  Perhaps that's a good point.  I'll keep digging in the php errors.  Bastiyan - Mysqli.  Sorry I didn't include that section to save space.

Comment: You can definitely have more than 2 parameters in a SQL statement.

Comment: But I guess it might be a syntax issue - how to express > 2

Comment: You can have as many parameters as you like, so that's not the issue. You need to do some debugging, check you actually have data, check the data in the php check the logs etx

Comment: No error in php log. (there was before so it is recording normally). Have I got the syntax correct with commas on all except the last one in the sql? And with the binding.  There is data going into the ajax query OK.

Comment: but it is not getting to the end of the ajax function because it doesn't return a success alert whereas it does with only the 2 parameters

Comment: So you need to do some debugging

Comment: That would suggest to me that the problem is with your javascript. Are there any errors in your console

Comment: Also, by check the data I mean var_dump in php and console.log in javascript to make sure your data looks how you expect

Comment: I think your right - debugging back to the brick!